# How to pass a system file path for an executable jar file of Java project?

Tags: java

I have a Java Project which takes XSD file path placed in my system as input and then it created an Excel sheet out of that XSD.
Below is how I pass XSD path in Java code:-

```
private static String schemaFileName = "D:/XSDFolder/Account.xsd";
```

Now I wanted to created an executable file for my Java project and pass it to other members so they can simply run this in theie system and can create Excel out of xsd file.
But I am not able to get how can I pass this xsd file path while running the executable jar file as this is a dynamic path and can change for different machines.

Any help would be appreciated here.

Comment: [Location-Independent Access to Resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html)

Answer (score 1):

Modify your Main-Class to receive arguments and act upon the argument:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

       String schemaFileName = args[0];
}
```

Specify the full path in the command-line:

```
java -jar YOURJAR D:/XSDFolder/Account.xsd
```

Answer (score -1):

Put your xsd file under the `resource` folder, and tries to read it in the relative path. Extract `jar` file with the xsd file.

```java
File file = new File(
    getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Account.xsd").getFile()
);
```

or you can set file path as input parameter for your executable jar, read it, just like command line parameters.

Comment: Hi @PatrickChen , the XSD file can also change , like there can be any XSD file not just Account.xsd. I will dig more in how to pass file path as input parameter for my executable Jar file. Thanks